# Switch view to a new file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to open a new file and then replace this empty file with the strings from my list. Each list item on a separate line. I am using Sublime 3. Currently my plugin opens the new file, but does not change the view to the new file to edit (add the strings from my list).

I have the following code:

```
size = len(TheList)
count = 0
view = self.view.window().new_file()
allcontent = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
while size!=count:
    self.view.replace(edit, allcontent, TheList)
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use:

```
self.view = self.view.window().new_file()
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain your solution? also, can you accept your answer so that the question is marked as closed?